# Number of images formed by 3 plane mirrors forming equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

> Three plane mirrors are kept as shown in the figure. A point object O is placed at the centroid of the system. How many images are formed?

[image]

The solution here made 3 circles, one for each pair of sides, each having 5 images (1 of them is actually 2 overlapping images). Then they said that clearly 1 image is common to each pair of circles. Thus out of the total 15 images, 3 are counted twice. So the answer is 12.

I understand the case of just 2 mirrors, and I know that for mirrors at $60\unicode{xB0}$, five images are formed. But here, when they make the circle for any 2 of the mirrors, it seems to me that they are ignoring the third mirror. In other words, they take each pair of mirrors while ignoring the third one, then "superimpose" the three circles to get the answer.

**My question**:  How do we know no additional images will be formed due to the third mirror? How can we consider each pair of mirrors as "isolated" from the third mirror and be sure that the third mirror won't change the result we get for just two mirrors?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - the count of $12$ images seems to only include images that involve reflections in just one mirror or in two of the mirrors and not in the third. This restriction seems arbitrary. If you allow reflections in any sequence of any of the three mirrors then you can see that there are an infinite number of distinct images because images of the triangle of three mirrors tesselate the plane.

Comment: Cool, thank you!